# EasyFormat.format error

Tags: java, string-formatting, bluej

I am a beginning programmer and I am confused about an error that I have recently encountered when trying to make a program.  I am trying to create a class called `EasyFormat` to arrange my output. However, I encounter an error that says:

```
cannot find symbol - method format(java.lang.String,int).
```

I am terribly confused on what to do and I have no clue as to what I am doing wrong.  If someone could help me, I would be really grateful.  Here is what my program looks like:

```
public class EasyFormat
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x = 0; int space;
        space = Math.abs((20 - (2 * x)));

        for(x = 0; x <= 21; x++)
        {
            if(x != 11)
            {
                System.out.println(EasyFormat.format("X",x)+EasyFormat.format("X",space));
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.printf("%11s", "X");
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you did not include the appropriate library for `EasyFormat` when you built your code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created method `format()` in your `EasyFormat` class. Thus, you should create method first like this:

```
private static int format(String string, int x) {
    // code for proper arrange output
    return 0;
}
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public class EasyFormat{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int x = 0; int space;
    space = Math.abs((20 - (2 * x)));

    for(x = 0; x <= 21; x++)
    {
        if(x != 11)
        {
        System.out.println(String.format("X",x)+String.format("X",space));
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.printf("%11s", "X");
        }
   }
}
```

}